# Hypercohomology of a complex via Cech cohomology

Tags: sheaf-theory, at.algebraic-topology, ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be a reasonable topological space. If $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf of abelian groups then Cech cohomology gives us a method to compute the cohomology groups $H^p(X, \mathcal{F})$ - the main input being the sections $\mathcal{F}(U)$ for various open sets $U \subset X$.

I would like to have a similar procedure to compute hypercohomology of a finite complex $C^\cdot$ of abelian sheaves on $X$ (or coherent sheaves on a scheme). Is this possible, and is there a reference you can recommend? I couldn't find this in the Stacks project, which incidently explains how to compute cohomology of a complex (not hypercohomology) via a Cech argument.

Comment: I can't think of a reference, but I have a vague recollection that this is how you do it: since the Cech complex of a sheaf is functorial, if we have a complex of sheaves $\mathcal{F}^{\cdot}$ 
we can take the Cech complex of each term to get a double complex $C^{\cdot,\cdot}$. Now just take the associated simple complex, $\mathrm{Tot}(C^{\cdot,\cdot})$ - in suitably nice situations, this computes hypercohomology of $\mathcal{F}^{\cdot}$.

Comment: Indeed regarding "sufficiently nice": it suffices that for each $n$, the complex $C^{n, \bullet}$ computes the cohomology of $\scr{F}^n$ (consider the spectral sequence taking "vertical cohomology" first). 

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice treatment of it in chapter 1 of [Brylisnki's *Loop Spaces, Characteristic Classes and Geometric Quantization*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ta5UB1D64_gC). In the Stacks projects, look for [section 19.19](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01FP).

Comment: Note that is is now Section 20.25. It's best to reference the tag, which is 01FP.